# High frequency data in ARIMA

Tags: time-series, python, arima

I am getting started using pmdarima and trying to resolve some confusion with m. I m appending to this related question and hoping you can clarify,
I am having 5-minute intervals data. The seasonality is one day in that case, m = 24*12.
When I try using auto_arima for 6 month of data with m=24x12, the process gets killed. How can I make this computationally feasible?

Comment: See https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/longseasonality/ and [threads](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=robjhyndman.com%2Fhyndsight%2Flongseasonality) that mention it.

Comment: @RichardHardy: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, I would rather identify a duplicate and mark this thread as such. Just do not have the time for it now.

Comment: @RichardHardy: good point. I proposed a duplicate that is pretty close, at least in terms of the resolution, if not in terms of the original question.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, thank you.